# Python SQLite3 Insert

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm getting an error when I insert values. My db has 3 columns. One autoincrement integer initialized here:

```
connection.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {tn} ({nf1} {ft1} PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)"\
    .format(tn = tableName, nf1 = "IDPK", ft1 = "INTEGER"))
```

and two text fields initialized like this:

```
connection.execute("ALTER TABLE {tn} ADD COLUMN '{cn}' {ct}".format(tn = tableName, cn = "foo", ct = "TEXT"))
connection.execute("ALTER TABLE {tn} ADD COLUMN '{cn}' {ct}".format(tn = tableName, cn = "bar", ct = "TEXT"))
```

the execution is here:

```
connection.execute("INSERT INTO {tn} VALUES (NULL, {col1}, {col2})".format(tn = tableName, col1 = text1, col2 = text2))
```

And the error thrown is:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: "obfuscatedTextStringInText1"
```

I don't understand why it thinks the name of the column is in text1. I'm inserting a value into columns 1 and 2 I thought with this syntax, as the autoincrement functions with the NULL keyword.

Comment: I think the default value for null is "" in sqlite3. Try just adding values for just columns col1 and col2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be quotes arround `{col1}` and `{col2}` since they are being inserted as text values. For example, it currently is being evaluated like:

```
"INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (NULL, my text 1, my text 2)"
```

Answer (score 3):

*Don't use string formatting to insert variables into the query.* It is dangerous (you are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)) and error-prompt (as you can already see).

Instead, *parameterize* your query:

```
connection.execute("""
    INSERT INTO 
        {tn} 
    VALUES 
        (NULL, :col1, :col2)""".format(tn=tableName), 
    {"col1": text1, "col2": text2})
```

Note that we [cannot parameterize table or column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247183/variable-table-name-in-sqlite) - make sure you validate and properly escape the `tableName`, or trust your source.

Answer (score 1):

> Don't use string formatting to insert variables into the query. It is
> dangerous (you are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks) and
> error-prompt (as you can already see).

(from [@alecxe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38272587/11107541)) I removed all string formatting for a safer example:

```
new_element={'col1': 'foo', 'col2': 'TEXT with special characters like " and *'}
connection.execute("INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (NULL, :col1, :col2)", new_element)
```