# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm receiving the error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error`
when I try to run the following code. 
    import sqlite3

```
def getFromDB(DBname,table, url):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(DBname)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = '''SELECT * FROM %s WHERE URL=%s'''
    stuff = cursor.execute(sql, (table,url))
    stuff = stuff.fetchall()
    return stuff

url = 'http://www.examplesite.com/'
getFromDB('AuthorData.sqlite','forbes',url)
```

I'm using parameters in my `SQL` query using `%s`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) module uses `?` as placeholder.

Comment: Tried that. I get the same error except instead of `%` It shows `?`.

Comment: Ah yes, missed that you're trying to pass an identifier (table's name). That'll not work using placeholders. That you have to format in to the string. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247183/variable-table-name-in-sqlite for example.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Or better yet, fix your schema so that you don't have to use dynamic table names.

Answer (score 1):

Some idea:
- Using parameter is not available for table name
- Using string format is not good because of sql-injection

So first, create a method to make table name safe:

```py
def escape_table_name(table):
    return '"%s"'.format(table.replace('"', '')
```

Then complete the code with escape table name and parameter using `?` for parameter:

```py
    sql = '''SELECT * FROM %s WHERE URL=?'''.format(escape_table_name(table))
    stuff = cursor.execute(sql, (url,))
    stuff = stuff.fetchall()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use :

```
sql = '''SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE URL= {1}'''.format(table, url)
```