# python sqlite inserting error

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using python 3  tkinter and sqlite 
I have data inside tkinter `Text Widget` and then  i need to split and save it in a data base table  here is my code attempts

```
data = txtReceipt.get("4.0" ,"end")

 for line in data.splitlines()[2:-2]:

     no = line.split()[2:3]
     name = line.split()[1:2]
     price = line.split()[3:4]
     series = line.split()[:1]
     print(no)
     c.execute("INSERT INTO  billed_items(item_name,billed_qty,price,item_bill_series) VALUES(?,?,?,?)",(name),(no),(price),(series))
     conn.commit()
```

but i am getting this error message `TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (5 given)`
any help please
here also when i am trying to read back into text widget

```
    su=c.execute("SELECT * FROM billed_items")
    for row in su:
            text = str(row)
            txtReceipt.insert("end",str(row[0])+"  "+str(row[1])+'\t\t'+str(row[2])+'\t'+"  "+str(row[3])+"\n")
```

in there it only reads the last row in the table i dont  know why he cant read all the rows

Comment: Please can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: You need to replace '?' with '%s'

Comment: @bigbounty yes bro but when i try this i am getting other error of `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error`

Comment: @suhaybabiib Why are you passing five arguments to a function that only accepts two arguments?

Answer (score 2):

The values need to be provided in a tuple. Try this

```
query = ("INSERT INTO  billed_items(item_name,billed_qty,price,item_bill_series) VALUES(?,?,?,?)")
c.execute(query,((name),(no),(price),(series))
conn.commit()
```

//[sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38925115/sqlite3-operationalerror-near-syntax-error)

Comment: thanks bro but still i am getting this error  `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error`

Comment: @suhaybabiib aah my bad, the SQLite module uses '?' instead of '%s' as the placeholder. i'll edit my response