# I'm trying to delete a record from my database table without using id but using a name that is in a row

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, sql-delete

I'm using SQLite3,

I'm trying to delete a record from my database table without using id but using a name that is in a row.

Here is the CODE:

```
import sqlite3

def delete_data(product_name):
    i_Delete = input(f"You Want To Delete {product_name} ?. (y/n) ")
    
    if i_Delete == 'y':
        # Connect to database
        connect_to_database = sqlite3.connect('database.db')

        # create a cursor
        c = connect_to_database.cursor()
        

        # delete record.
        c.execute("DELETE from data WHERE produit = product_name")

        # commit the command.
        connect_to_database.commit()

        # close the DB
        connect_to_database.close()
        
    elif i_Delete == 'n':
        pass
    else:
        print("Sorry Bad Input. \nPlease Verify Your Input")
        
delete_data('Cheeseburger')
```

Then i get this error instead of delete it.

```
You Want To Delete Cheeseburger ?. (y/n) y

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deleteDB.py", line 29, in <module>
    delete_data('Cheeseburger')
  File "deleteDB.py", line 16, in delete_data
    c.execute("DELETE from data WHERE produit = product_name")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: product_name
```

As i can see the problem is here on `product = product_name`

```
# delete record.
c.execute("DELETE from data WHERE product = product_name")
```

So What can i do, Please Help !

Comment: You’re missing quotes, if `product_name` is supposed to be a text literal, and not a column name.

Comment: _“without using id but using a name”_ - why? That appears to make rather little sense to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you use the name of the variable (instead of its value) to be looked for.

You need to provide a parameter to the [`execute`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) statement:

```
c.execute("DELETE from data WHERE produit = ?", [product_name])
```

Please note, that you are supposed to provide a list with parameters, therefore `[product_name]` instead of `product_name`.

Another option is to use a dictionary:

```
c.execute("DELETE from data WHERE produit = :product_name", {'product_name': product_name})
```

Comment: Now the error turn to this:
  File "deleteDB.py", line 16, in delete_data
    c.execute("DELETE from data WHERE produit = %", [product_name])
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

Comment: @red_ant: corrected. It seems that Python API supports `?` instead of `%` as [this questions' answers suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38925115/sqlite3-operationalerror-near-syntax-error)

Comment: Thanks, I use ? instead of % now it works Thanks.