# How to use variable for SQLite table name

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x

I have a program where the user can select what table they want to modify in SQLite. I store the selection in a variable called `table`, then try and select everything from that table

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM ?', (table,))
```

The program gets stuck at the question mark. It says:

> "Sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use *parameter* substitution for the *table name*. You need to add the table name to the query string yourself. Something like this:

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM {}'.format(table)
c.execute(query)
```

One thing to be mindful of is the source of the value for the table name. If that comes from an untrusted source, e.g. a user, then you need to validate the table name to avoid potential SQL injection attacks. One way might be to construct a parameterised query that looks up the table name from the DB catalogue:

```
import sqlite3

def exists_table(db, name):
    query = "SELECT 1 FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' and name = ?"
    return db.execute(query, (name,)).fetchone() is not None
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you

Comment: I think I did that. The program first gets a list of names of the tables and displays them. Then the user has to input one of those names. If the input doesn't match a name on the list the program goes back to the list of table names and asks for input again.

Comment: @Josh: that should be safe. I've also added to my answer a way to verify the user entered table name against SQLite's master table.

Comment: hey, does sb know how I can verify the input if it comes from an user and the table doesn't exists? Because I have a function to create a table