# Populating SQLite table with JSON data, getting: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "x": syntax error

Tags: python, sql, json, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a SQLite database with four tables named restaurants, bars, attractions, and lodging. Each table has 3 columns named id, name, and description. I am trying to populate the database with data from a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
  "restaurants": [
    {"id": "ChIJ8xR18JUn5IgRfwJJByM-quU", "name": "Columbia", "description": "Traditional Spanish restaurant, a branch of a long-standing local chain dating back to 1905."},
  ],
  "bars": [
    {"id": "ChIJ8aLBaJYn5IgR60p2CS_RHIw", "name": "Harrys", "description": "Chain outpost serving up Creole dishes in a leafy courtyard or on a balcony overlooking the bay."},
  ],
  "attractions": [
    {"id": "ChIJvRwErpUn5IgRaFNPl9Lv0eY", "name": "Flagler", "description": "Flagler College was founded in 1968. Formerly one of Henry Flagler's hotels, the college is allegedly home to many spirits. Tours are offered"},
  ],
  "lodging": [
    {"id": "ChIJz8NmD5Yn5IgRfgnWL-djaSM", "name": "Hemingway", "description": "Cottage-style B&B offering a gourmet breakfast & 6 rooms with private baths & traditional decor."},
  ]
}
```

Whenever the script tries to execute the query, I get `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "x": syntax error` where x is a random word from one of the descriptions. An example error looks like this: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "Spanish": syntax error`. The word is not always Spanish but it is always a word from one of the descriptions.

I have tried a couple different methods but always get the same result, here is one method I have tried:

```
import sqlite3
import json

places = json.load(open('locations.json'))
db = sqlite3.connect('data.db')

for place, data in places.items():
    table = place
    for detail in data:
        query = 'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ' + place + ' VALUES (?, ?, ?), (' \
                + detail['id'] + ',' + detail['name'] + ',' + detail['description'] + ')'
        c = db.cursor()
        c.execute(query)
        c.close()
```

And I also tried writing the query like this:

```
query = 'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {} VALUES ({}, {}, {})'\
          .format(table, detail['id'], detail['name'], detail['description'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current problem is the *missing quotes* around the string values in the query.

You need to *properly parameterize your query* letting the database driver worry about the type conversions, putting quotes properly and escaping the parameters:

```
query = """
    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO 
        {} 
    VALUES 
        (?, ?, ?)""".format(table)

c.execute(query, (detail['id'], detail['name'], detail['description']))
```

Note that the [table name cannot be parameterized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247183/variable-table-name-in-sqlite) - we have to use string formatting to insert it into the query - make sure the table name is coming from a source you trust or/and properly validate it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I was pretty sure that was the problem from what I read, unfortunately, when I try your method I get `c.execute(query, (detail['id'], detail['name'], detail['description'])) sqlite3.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch`

Comment: @GrantJordan ah, okay, what happens if you specify the column name explicitly after the table name, e.g. `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {} (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`

Comment: OK, the datatype mismatch error was because I made the id column an Integer instead of Text and my id's are alphanumeric. Thank you for your help, the script runs now with no errors!