# SQLite3 and Python 3 - "no such column" error with strings but not integers

Tags: python, database, sqlite, operationalerror

For this project, I have a database file with a table RESULTS which looks like this:

```
conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE RESULTS(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
name TEXT NOT NULL,
age TEXT NOT NULL,
gender TEXT NOT NULL);''')
```

And this is the file I'm using to create a prototype front end so that users can access the data in the database:

```
#setting up the user input variables
srcIn = input("what field do you want to search: id, name, age, or gender? ")
srcQuery = input("what result do you want to find from the "+ srcIn + " search? ")
if(srcIn == "age") or (srcIn == "id"):
    #by default input returns a string but it needs to be an int for age and id parameters
    srcQuery = int(srcQuery)
    print("converted to int")
srcOut = input("what field do you want to return: id, name, age, or gender? ")

print("making cursor")
cursor = conn.execute("SELECT %s FROM RESULTS WHERE %s = %s" % (srcOut, srcIn, srcQuery))
for row in cursor:
    print(srcOut + ": " + row[0])

conn.close()
print("closed database " + db)
```

If I were to run this and pass it age or id, the number 45, and name it would return the names, genders, and other stats from my database perfectly. However, when I pass it gender, and female or male, and returning the names or ages or ids, an error would pop up saying this:

```
cursor = conn.execute("SELECT %s FROM RESULTS WHERE %s = %s" % (srcOut, srcIn, srcQuery))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: male
```

For this specific example:

```
srcOut = name
srcIn = gender
srcQuery = male
```

I've tried replacing the %s with ? arguments (I know it won't work on the parameters that I'm passing to the SELECT statement), so I'm stumped.

I think that it has something to do with the fact that in certain instances I'm passing it an integer in the srcQuery field and in others I'm passing it a string.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you should not be doing it the way @Suever has suggested**.

Imagine what  query would be executed if I provide the following values:

```
srcOut = "name"
srcIn = "gender"
srcQuery = "' or 1 = 1 -- "
```

Your code would actually execute:

```
SELECT 
    name 
FROM 
    RESULTS 
WHERE  
    gender = '' or 1 = 1 -- '
```

*This will match every single row in the table.*

Or, in other words, because of the lack of any validation and escaping and by preparing a specific input I'm getting all the results in a table which is, of course, what you don't want to happen in real world. This is called an [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Instead of string formatting, you should *parameterize your query*. [Query parameterization though is not going to work for table and column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247183/variable-table-name-in-sqlite)  - these you need to validate before inserting into the query - since the amount of possible values for `scrIn` and `srcOut` is very limited - I'd simply throw an error if you see an unexpected value, e.g.:

```
columns = {'id', 'name', 'age', 'gender'} 
srcIn = input("what field do you want to search: id, name, age, or gender? ")
if srcIn not in columns:
    raise ValueError("Invalid srcIn value")
```

As for the `srcQuery` - this one you need to *parameterize*:

```
query = "SELECT {column_out} FROM RESULTS WHERE {column_in} = ?".format(column_out=srcOut, column_in=scrIn)
cursor = conn.execute(query, (srcQuery, ))
```

Aside from being much safer, this would also eliminate the problem of thinking about python-to-database type conversions and quotes - the database driver would handle that automatically.