# how to insert variables in read_sql_query using python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to retrieve data from sqlite3 with the help of variables. It is working fine with `execute()` statement but i would like to retrieve columns also and for that purpose i am using `read_sql_query()` but i am unable to pass variables in `read_sql_query()`, please follow below code:

```
def cal():
  tab = ['LCOLOutput']
  column_name = 'CUSTOMER_EMAIL_ID'
  xyz = '**AVarma1@ra.rockwell.com'
  for index, m in enumerate(tab):
      table_name = m
      sq = "SELECT * FROM ? where ?=?;" , (table_name, column_name, xyz,)
      df = pandas.read_sql_query(sq,conn)
      writer = 
      pandas.ExcelWriter('D:\pandas_simple.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
      df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
      writer.save()
```

Comment: I am facing this error-SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file D:/Automation/TicketAuditDefects/exp.py on line 90, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: Hi I am facing still this error - "pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM ? where ?=?': near "?": syntax error"

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the syntax with the method `read_sql_query()` from `pandas`, check the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html#pandas-read-sql-query).

For sqlite, it should work with :

```
sq = "SELECT * FROM ? where ?=?;" 
param = (table_name, column_name, xyz,)
df = pandas.read_sql_query(sq,conn, params=param)
```

---

EDIT : 
otherwise try with the following formatting for the table :

```
sq = "SELECT * FROM {} where ?=?;".format(table_name)
param = (column_name, xyz,)
df = pandas.read_sql_query(sq,conn, params=param)
```

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3247553/6655211) explaining why table cannot be passed as parameter directly.

Comment: Hi PRMoureu, I am facing this error "pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM ? where ?=?': near "?": syntax error"

Comment: Hi PRMoureu, This is working fine-"        sq = "SELECT * FROM {} where {}=?;".format(table_name,column_name)
        param = (xyz,)
        df = pandas.read_sql_query(sq, conn, params=param)"

Comment: nice, sorry for the first answer, i didnt pay attention for the table blocking

Comment: no need of sorry dude atleast you tried to answer my question, for me it is a big thing, i thought my question will drown some where in sea

Comment: You'll also have to treat the column name as an object. Paramaters are *explicitly only for values*, because the database driver will make sure to escape the notation such that it can't ever be mistaken for an object name (table, column name, index, etc.) or SQL syntax.