# SQL SELECT from table name supplied by a variable

Tags: python, sql, database

Whenever I try the code below, I get `near "?": syntax error`
I tried multiple things including prepping it into a variable

Is this possible in python? Or am I thinking in the wrong direction?

```
import sqlite3
sqlite_file = 'DATABASE.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
c = conn.cursor()
word = ()
question = int(input("What would you like to see?"))
if question == 1:
    word = ("Batchnumbers")
if question == 2:
    word = ("Worker IDs")
c.execute('SELECT * FROM ?', (word))
    data = c.fetchall()
    for x in range(len(data)):
        print(data[x])
```

Comment: which database package are you using because you can't just insert the table name into the query like that, like you could other params

Comment: I'm using sqlite3

Comment: afaik there is no option to safely execute a SQL query with the table name being the param in `sqlite3`, using string interpolation is also unsafe, check here as they give examples --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247183/variable-table-name-in-sqlite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed use this line of code
    word =

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM "{}"'.format(word))
```

Answer (score 4):

Query parameters can only be used to supply column *values*, not table or column *names*. If you need to supply a table name you will have to use dynamic SQL, e.g.,

```python
c.execute('SELECT * FROM "{}"'.format(word))
```

Note that this approach is vulnerable to SQL injection issues, so you really should consider mitigating those, e.g., ensuring that `word` does not contain double-quote characters that would cause errors (or worse).

Comment: Thanks, working like a charm! totally forgot about that!(while I was using it in other queries... _damn_)