# How to "format" column names and types into python sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a function that I want to use when mass creating tables.
This is the function:

```py
def make_tables(tablenames: list, cursor: sql.Cursor, parameters, connection: sql.Connection):
    for i in tablenames:
        cursor.execute(f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '{scrub(i)}' ('{parameters}')")
    connection.commit()
```

My parameters variable is `parameters = 'name text, id integer'`
what it does, is create a table with one column, called 'name text, id integer' and type unknown.
The solutions from here: [Python sqlite3, create table columns from a list with help of .format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54870929/python-sqlite3-create-table-columns-from-a-list-with-help-of-format) don't work.
I will have different names and types as input, and the number of columns will vary.
What ways are there to solving this problem?

Comment: Don't put quotes around `{parameters}`. That's making it a single string, not parsing it as separate parameters.

Comment: put that as an answer please so I can accept it

Comment: I voted to close this question as a simple typo, it's not worth answering.

Comment: but i meant to type the single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put quotes around `{parameters}`, that turns it into a single parameter definition.

```
        cursor.execute(f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '{scrub(i)}' ({parameters})")
```