# Use placeholder for table name in python sqlite3

Tags: python, discord.py, sqlite3-python

I was wondering if there was a way to use the '?' to create a table with a different name every time in a function.
Here's my code:

```
@bot.tree.command(name='create', description='Crea un nuovo torneo')
@app_commands.describe(name='Il nome del torneo', max_participants='Numero massimo di partecipanti', 
                       date='Data del torneo(mm:hh:dd:MM:yyyy)', mode='Modalità del torneo', 
                       mappa='Mappa del torneo')
async def create(interaction:discord.Interaction, name:str, max_participants:int, date:str, 
                 mode:str, mappa:str):
    date = datetime.datetime(year=int((date.split(':'))[4]), month=int((date.split(':'))[3]), 
                             day=int((date.split(':'))[2]), hour=int((date.split(':'))[1]), 
                             minute=int((date.split(':'))[0]), second=0)
    conn = sqlite3.connect('tourneys.sqlite3')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS (?) (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, max_participants INTEGER, date DATETIME, mode TEXT, map TEXT)',
              (name, )) # error here
    t_id = (random.randint(0,9) for _ in range(9))
    c.execute('INSERT INTO ? VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (name, t_id, max_participants, date, mode, mappa))
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM ? WHERE id = ?', (name, t_id))
    t = c.fetchone()
    await interaction.response.send_message(t)
```

Error: Command 'create' raised an exception: OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

PS: I know you can't use placeholders columns/tables names but I have seen someone doing something like .'''format and I didn't really understand what was going on.

I tried to use placeholders in my table name and I expected that it created a table with the placeholder name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable table name in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247183/variable-table-name-in-sqlite)

Comment: Looks like it's impossible to use parameter binding for table names. Be careful with string substitution, especially when the table name is what looks like a user-defined string. Injection is the obvious risk, but there could be all sorts of illegal characters in `name`. Sanitization is mandatory, but naively removing illegal characters could result in name collision, i.e. two unique names which, when stripped of illegal characters, result in the same table name.

Answer (score 0):

of course you can use f string instead.

instead of the following code:

```
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS (?) (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, max_participants INTEGER, date DATETIME, mode TEXT, map TEXT)',
              (name, )) # error here
```

use this code:

```
table_name = 'some name assigned in run time'
# if the table name is coming from user you should causes of SQL injection. avoid harmness using .qoute() method like following
table_name = sqlite3.qoute(table_name)

c.execute(f'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, max_participants INTEGER, date DATETIME, mode TEXT, map TEXT)',
                  (name, ))
```

Comment: This code generates an exception: `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied.` The second argument to `c.execute()`, `(name, )`, should be removed.